# How can i create a centos yum public repo

Tags: centos, yum

I have some valid .rpm files. and want to create a public-facing yum repo. where any can install the yum repo and install the rpm files over the internet.

Comment: Good question. Have you looked into `createrepo` utility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a **public** yum repository, you need:

- a machine with a public IP
- running a web server (nginx, apache, ...)
- serving the directory with your rpm files
- create the repository metadata inside that directory using `createrepo`